# A question about constructing one single rotation matrix from Andrew Hanson's Visualizing Quarternion

Tags: matrices

I've a question about constructing one single rotation matrix when I read Andrew Hanson's  book .

To make it clear, one single rotation matrix is defined as follows(at page 46 of the book):
[image]

Here's the screenshot discussing the construction of one single rotation matrix(page 47):

[image]

My question is for para 3. Although from the view of linear algebra, it is simple to prove that R(θ,n) is the eigenvector of n, I could not understand this from the view of geometry. As Para 3 writes, "transform n to z by inverting the previously cited transformation, spin about z by θ using the elementary matrix Rz(θ), and tilt z back to the direction n". I just cannot link these operations with the geometric meaning of one single rotation matrix, **especially why multiply last two transpose matrices**.

Answer (score 1):

When Hanson writes "transform $\hat{\boldsymbol{n}}$ to $\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}$ by inverting the previously cited transformation" he means
$$\tag{1}
\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}=\boldsymbol{R}^T_y(\beta)\cdot\boldsymbol{R}^T_z(\alpha)\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{n}}\,.
$$
Then he wants you to "spin about $\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}$ by $\theta$ using the elementary matrix $\boldsymbol{R}_z(\theta)\,$" he means
$$\tag{2}
\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}=\boldsymbol{R}_z(\theta)\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}\,.
$$
Finally he wants you to "tild $\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}$ [i.e. the result of (2)] back to the direction $\hat{\boldsymbol{n}}$ where it started":
$$\tag{3}
\hat{\boldsymbol{n}}=\boldsymbol{R}_z(\alpha)\cdot\boldsymbol{R}_y(\beta)\cdot \hat{\boldsymbol{z}}\,.
$$
Putting together (1-3) yields
$$\tag{4}
\hat{\boldsymbol{n}}=\underbrace{\boldsymbol{R}_z(\alpha)\cdot\boldsymbol{R}_y(\beta)\cdot \boldsymbol{R}_z(\theta)\cdot\boldsymbol{R}^T_y(\beta)\cdot\boldsymbol{R}^T_z(\alpha)}_{\textstyle\boldsymbol{R}(\theta,\hat{\boldsymbol n})}\cdot \hat{\boldsymbol{n}}\,.
$$
This shows that $\hat{\boldsymbol{n}}$ is the rotation axis of the matrix $\boldsymbol{R}(\theta,\hat{\boldsymbol n})$ we constructed. You can view the symmetric appearances of $\boldsymbol{R}_z(\alpha)$ and $\boldsymbol{R}_y(\beta)$ and their transposes around $\boldsymbol{R}_z(\theta)$ similar to $D=SAS^T$ when you diagonalize a matrix by a change of basis.